# How to stop asynchronous database calls in nodejs/knexjs

Tags: node.js, database, asynchronous, knex.js

So I've been stuck on this problem for the last week I'd say.
I'm trying to add a workout to my database and I'm receiving from my frontend 3 things: the workout name as a string, an array called `exercises` that contains objects for each exercise in that workout. And finally, an array called `sets` that is a 2d array, each array contains an object for each set

```js
    const exercises = [
        {name: ''}
    ]

    const sets = [
        [
            {
                reps: '',
                kg: ''
            }
        ]
    ]
```

I'm using knex and I want to insert this data into my database. This is my code:

```js
    app.post('/newworkout', (req, res) => {
        const {workoutName, exercises, sets} = req.body;
        const loggedSets = [];
        let haveRoutinesFinished = false;
        let haveExercisesFinished = false;

        PushRoutinesToDB = () => {
            db('routines')
                .returning('id')
                .insert({
                    userid: user.id,
                    name: workoutName
                })
                .then(routineID => {
                    workoutInfo.routineID =  routineID[0];
                    haveRoutinesFinished = true;
                    console.log('1')
                    return db('loggedroutines')
                        .insert({ 
                            userid: user.id,
                            routineid: workoutInfo.routineID,
                            routinedate: new Date() 
                        })
                })
        }
        
        PushExercisesToDB = () => {
            exercises.map(exercise => {
            console.log('2')
            db('exercises')
                .insert({
                    userid: user.id,
                    routineid: workoutInfo.routineID,
                    name: exercise.name
                })
                .returning('id')
                .then(exerciseID => {
                    console.log('exercise id', exerciseID)
                    exerciseIDArray.push(exerciseID[0])
                    console.log("exerciseIDArray", exerciseIDArray)
                    haveExercisesFinished = true;
                    return db('loggedexercises')
                        .insert({
                            userid: user.id,
                            routineid: workoutInfo.routineID,
                            exerciseid: exerciseID[0]
                        })
                })
            })
            
        }
            
        PushSetsToDB = () => {
            sets.map((setsArray, i) => {
                setsArray.map(set => {
                    loggedSets.push({
                        userid: user.id,
                        routineid: workoutInfo.routineID,
                        exerciseid: exerciseIDArray[i],
                        reps: set.reps,
                        kg: set.kg
                    })
                })
            })
            console.log(loggedSets)
        
            db('loggedsets').insert(loggedSets)
        }

        PushRoutinesToDB()
        console.log(haveRoutinesFinished)
        if (haveRoutinesFinished === true) {
            PushExercisesToDB()
        }

        if (haveExercisesFinished === true) {
            PushSetsToDB()
        }

    })
```

The code itself works, but due to the first database call being asynchronous, the second one doesn't work and it depends on the first one. I tried to use callbacks to counter this issue but that just causes my code to not run. Any ideas?

Comment: You have to use async/await in your first database call which will wait for the promise to resolve and then continue.

Comment: @AshutoshKumar. How do I implement it?

Comment: I've added an answer just to show that. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your functions are `Asynchronous` the thread continues even if the first function has not yet completed.

Using `async/await` must solve your problem.

**NOTE THE COMMENTS TO SEE CHANGES**

```js
    app.post('/newworkout', async (req, res) => { //asynchronous Function
        const {workoutName, exercises, sets} = req.body;
        const loggedSets = [];
        let haveRoutinesFinished = false;
        let haveExercisesFinished = false;

        PushRoutinesToDB = async () => { //asynchronous Function
            db('routines')
                .returning('id')
                .insert({
                    userid: user.id,
                    name: workoutName
                })
                .then(routineID => {
                    workoutInfo.routineID =  routineID[0];
                    haveRoutinesFinished = true;
                    console.log('1')
                    return db('loggedroutines')
                        .insert({ 
                            userid: user.id,
                            routineid: workoutInfo.routineID,
                            routinedate: new Date() 
                        })
                })
        }
        
        PushExercisesToDB = async () => { //asynchronous Function
            exercises.map(exercise => {
            console.log('2')
            db('exercises')
                .insert({
                    userid: user.id,
                    routineid: workoutInfo.routineID,
                    name: exercise.name
                })
                .returning('id')
                .then(exerciseID => {
                    console.log('exercise id', exerciseID)
                    exerciseIDArray.push(exerciseID[0])
                    console.log("exerciseIDArray", exerciseIDArray)
                    haveExercisesFinished = true;
                    return db('loggedexercises')
                        .insert({
                            userid: user.id,
                            routineid: workoutInfo.routineID,
                            exerciseid: exerciseID[0]
                        })
                })
            })
            
        }
            
        PushSetsToDB = async () =>  {  //asynchronous Function
            sets.map((setsArray, i) => {
                setsArray.map(set => {
                    loggedSets.push({
                        userid: user.id,
                        routineid: workoutInfo.routineID,
                        exerciseid: exerciseIDArray[i],
                        reps: set.reps,
                        kg: set.kg
                    })
                })
            })
            console.log(loggedSets)
        
            db('loggedsets').insert(loggedSets)
        }

    // Now your all functions are asynchronous You can call them in series with 'await'

    await PushRoutinesToDB()
    await PushExercisesToDB()
    await PushSetsToDB()
    })
```

Comment: Thank you so much man, I had to work a bit more on the code but it works now :) @Ashutosh Kumar